# get the information of users who have shared my websites content in facebook using faacebook share

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook's share button in my page where the users can share the blog in facebook. My question is can i get the public information of the profile(users) where my blog have been shared/ who have shared my blog? If So, how can i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i get the public information of the profile(users) where my blog have been shared/ who have shared my blog?

No, you can not.

At most you can get the *number* of shares, but you don’t get any info about which individual users did the shares.

Comment: for Instance, In W3 Templates, when we can download the template only if we share it to our FB page, In this case they will be fetching some sort of data right? Link https://my.w3layouts.com/DownloadTemplate/23495

Comment: Forcing people to share to get some kind of reward, is absolutely not allowed. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4 When you come across sites like this, you should report them, not try to imitate their behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But no, i am not going to imitate them. I was just wondering how they could get user data while sharing. I am sure we could get some sort of user data while logging via Facebook to our website.Even for sharing a blog from our website, another window will pop up for login and they could share our content. What details will fb return for this case?

Comment: Facebook will not return you _any_ data any more directly, based on a share action. All ways to get such feedback from the involved dialogs have been removed, explicitly to prevent this kind of behavior. A site _could_ ask for permission to read a user’s posts, and try and use that to verify if the actually shared. But that would of course be a total abuse of that permission. This will not fly in app review, so they would have to cheat there already. And Facebook will surely shut this down, once they notice.